# Definition of Enlargement (Homothetic Transformation: Negative Scale Factor)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$\textbf{Question:}$ It says on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) that an enlargement of a figure can be described when the scale factor exceeds one. Shouldn't it be when the absolute value of the scale factor exceeds one (i.e. $|\lambda|>1$)?

$\textbf{Opinion:}$ I also wanted to point out this question has been brought up here as [well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Homothetic_transformation). The problem I see here is that the definition for $\lambda$ is never defined to be new distance over old. It is clear that a figure is getting larger iff $|\lambda|>1$ for this situation. I think an enlargement should be defined here to be when $|\lambda|>1$ which then implies $|\lambda|$ is the ratio of which distances are multiplied. However, that is just my opinion.

Comment: If you read that Wikipedia entry more carefully, you'll se that the scale factor is indeed defined as $|\lambda|$.